# EF CORE after scaffold shows my connection string in the context file

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I use this command to do database first.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=localhost;port=3306;userid=root;password=****;database=*******;persistsecurityinfo=True" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -o DataService/ModelsByMicroservice/Security --context-dir DataService/DBContexts -c SecurityContext -f
```

But I don't know if there is a flag to dont put my connection string in the context file.
After the scaffolding there is these method in my context file

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
                optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;port=3306;userid=root;password=*****;database=*****;persistsecurityinfo=True");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this option:

```
--no-onconfiguring
```